# How to modify a query parameter in AWS API Gateway in the integration request for an HTTP Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a client facing API that takes a query parameter `Time`. The format is `14:00:00`. Originally it would pass through this query parameter to the back end endpoint. However the back end endpoint (that I do not control) is now expecting time in the format `0001-01-01T14:00:00`.

Is it possible to to modify the value of the query param before passing it on in AWS API Gateway?

I know you can modify the request body with a mapping template, and in the template you can access the `queryParameters`, but can you *change* them so that it modifies the actual request made to the back end?

I saw this:

> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=696524&#696524

but the user said he gave up trying to modify

---

Potential workaround I can think of right now are pass the parameters to a lambda and have the lambda build and make the request with modified values, with the response as the return value for the lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you basically answered your own question :)

1. There is no way to transform query or header request parameters. All transformations need to happen in the body mapping template.
2. Best workaround would be to forward request on to a Lambda function to massage the parameters into the expected shape

Answer (score 2):

For now one can overrides query string in Mapping Templates using velocity templates e.g:

```
$context.requestOverride.querystring.time="_your_transformed_data_"
```

There is [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html#apigateway-override-request-response-parameters-javascript-sdk)